# get output with linebreaks

Tags: php, html, database

This is a small part of my script, the `['messsage']` takes the message from the database but the output is without linebreaks (`<br>`)

```
 <td><?php echo $dnn2['message']; ?></td>
```

Does someone know how I get the output with linebreaks?

Comment: Can you explain more clearly

Comment: you mean with new line?... put it inside the `<pre></pre>` tag.

Comment: can you tell me in db the message is save with br or \n newline

Comment: tnx :) but sorry how should I place it in my script?

Answer (score 4):

use **nl2br** see =>http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

```
 <td><?php echo nl2br($dnn2['message']); ?></td>
```